# The Text in button is shifting left from center on checking a check box in list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have created a screen which consist of three horizontal button in a table layout and a list view.
Whenever i click on a check box present in the list view the text present in the button shifts to the left.
Kindly resolve the issue.
Please refer the screen layout code and the screen shots for same.

```
<RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

         <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

             <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" 
                                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                                android:background="@color/list_select" android:weightSum="3">

          <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                  android:id="@+id/set" 
                  android:text="@string/button_settings_done" 
                  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_settings_margin_top" 
                  android:textColor="@color/buttonColor" 
                  android:textStyle="bold" 
                  android:typeface="serif" android:layout_weight="1">

          </Button>
          <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:text="@string/button_settings_cancel"
                  android:id="@+id/cancel"
                  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_settings_margin_top"
                  android:textColor="@color/buttonColor"
                  android:textStyle="bold" 
                  android:typeface="serif" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>


          <Button
              android:id="@+id/delete"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_settings_margin_top"
              android:text="@string/button_settings_delete"
              android:textColor="@color/buttonColor"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:typeface="serif" android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

```
          <ListView
              android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_above="@+id/TableLayout01"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent" android:divider="@color/list_select" android:dividerHeight="@dimen/list_settings_divider_height">

          </ListView>
```

Screen shots
[image: Before checking checkbox]
[image: After checking]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text in Button Changing on clicking other controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331640/text-in-button-changing-on-clicking-other-controls)

Answer (score -3):

its weird but try this...
when you are clicking on a check box present in the list view..there on OnClick method..set the text of these button again..like

```
btn1.setText("Done");
btn2.setText("Cancel");
btn3.setText("Delete");
```

It worked very well in my case..I had the same problem.
hope this helps you

Comment: Try rewriting in standard written English, please, with correct spelling and punctuation.  This is not a lolcatz site.